# How often can we pull an all-nighter until the body is irreversible damaged?

Tags: sleep, sleep-deprivation, irreversible-damage, circadian-rythym, young-adults

Many jobs in medicine, science, and economy require unsuitable commitment especially for early-career people. This can often lead to extension of the daily work far into the night.

Assume a 30-year-old works 8 hours a day and sleeps for 8 hours at night. Twice a week, s/he skips sleeping by pulling an all-nighter. One could try to recover from that long wake phase by sleeping a bit longer the next night. Assume the person follows this procedure for decades.

- How often can this be safely done before the bodys suffers from
  serious damage?
- Should one stop at a certain age to prevent serious injury?
- What organs suffer the most?